# I don't need an output of a function, how to give it undeclared address to store that output

Tags: c, function, memory-address, variable-declaration

I just started learning C.

I have a function with two outputs, a value and an estimated error.

```
double result, abserr;
gsl_deriv_central (&f_var, rho, 1e-8, &result,&abserr);
```

I only care about the result. So my question is, can I skip the declaration of absolute error abserr. And give as input something like:

```
double result;    
gsl_deriv_central (&f_var, rho, 1e-8, &result,&SOMEWHERE);
```

Suggests better tags, if it seems incomplete.

Comment: Why can't you just ignore the value of `abserr`? Or write a wrapper.

Comment: Does the function allow a null pointer for the error argument?  Probably not, but read the documentation.

Comment: @SparKot If I don't declare abserr, or I don't give a corresponding argument, compillation fails. I'm looking for a slight quality of life change. I understand it might not be possible. I'm not familliar enough with writting wrappers, and I'm not sure I understand how it owuld help.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Are you suggesting declaring: "int *p= NULL;" globally, and passing &p in place of &abserror?

Comment: No: I'm suggesting `gsl_deriv_central (&f_var, rho, 1e-8, &result, NULL);`.  But only if the documentation says it is allowed.

Comment: If `NULL` doesn't work and you do not wish to use the address of a dummy local variable, then you could use the address of a compound literal like this: `gsl_deriv_central (&f_var, rho, 1e-8, &result, &(double){0});`

Comment: However, note that compound literals such as `(double){0}` were added in the 2011 version of the C standard (C11), so a dummy local variable might be a better option if you need to use an older compiler.

Comment: @IanAbbott I had tried NULL, and it didn't work. The compound literal is exaclty what I was looking for. I didn't even know if it existed, but seemed intutive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, first check if the library supports this call:

```
int status = gsl_deriv_central (&f_var, rho, 1e-8, &result, NULL);
```

If it doesn't use a wrapper like :

```c
static inline int
my_gsl_deriv_central (const gsl_function *f_var, double rho, double step, double* result) {
    double abserr;
    return gsl_deriv_central (f_var, rho, step, result, &abserr);
}
```

You call `my_gsl_deriv_central` from your translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

Original function:

```
void gsl_deriv_central(f_type *f_var, double rho, double bar, double *result, double *abserr)
{
 ...
}
```

`f_type` is whatever type used for the first parameter of the `gsl_deriv_central` function (which is unknown to me).

Wrapper:

```
void gsl_deriv_central2(f_type *f_var, double rho, double bar, double *result)
{
  double dummy;   // dummy variable, we just ignore it

  // call original function
  gsl_deriv_central(f_var, rho, bar, result, &dummy);
 ...
}
```

Call the wrapper function like this

```
double result;    
gsl_deriv_central2(&f_var, rho, 1e-8, &result);
```